# To what does "ip filtering" refer in the context of user authentication?

Tags: authentication

I'm looking at a set of requirements for a web site and it lists, among other things:

- User authentication - cookies and ip filtering

I understand what ip filtering is (forwarding or ignoring packets based on data such as packet type, source ip address, etc.), but how is this used to authenticate users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website has a list of blacklisted/whitelisted IP addresses, and denies access to everyone on the blacklist/not on the whitelist. E.g. users need to log into a gateway server whose IP is whitelisted, and can then access your site from there.

Comment: I can see how this makes sense if I'm serving up a site to a single organization (e.g., an intranet), but what is the value of having a user log into a gateway server instead of having them log into the site directly?

Comment: Practical purposes. For example, if you have a large userbase but also fairly strict requirements as to what machines you put on your whitelist: it's easier to have a handful of trusted gateways than ensure that every single user's machine meets your standards.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be to ban a user by his IP address...